# Spring Tool Suite (STS) launch error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

The STS was working fine until I recently upgraded the Java version.

Here's the **Error message I am getting on STS Launch -**

[image]

**Here's my Java version -**

[image]

**I've installed the 32 bit JRE now, STS is opening now but, here's the new Error -** 
[image]

Comment: it suggest you to use 32bit in STS and your JDK version is 64bit try to change your JDK version

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I am new to Java.

Comment: uninstall the 64 bits version and install the 32 bits

Comment: ok so installing 32 bit STS will solve this issue?

Comment: the problem is the JDK version now ,so you can try to change your JDK ,if it can't work you can show the another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your both 32 bit and 64 bit JRE to latest versions,  It will solve the issue.

In ideal world if your sts is 32 bit then you need to have 32 bit JRE latest version.

Comment: Should I download the 32 bit STS, will that solve the problem?

Comment: Upgrading JRE is best solution as it acts as dual purposes of starting your STS and will help ful for other applications which use java

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: At the time of writing jre 1.8.101 is the latest version Available , so update both 32 bit and 64 bit version to this version, it will definitely solve issue as I too faced the same issue

Comment: Follow above link and try to install, I see you have latest 64 bit so you need 32 bit JRE to be installed

Comment: Installed the 32 bit JRE, from the Link you gave me, Launched the STS again, I threw me some Errors, An internal error occurred during "Initializing Java Tooling" and "Update Installed JREs" , I have update the question with the image Error.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to download 32bit JDK and then change the JDK you have install and change the environment path to the 32 bit JDK.

Comment: Should I download the 32 bit STS, will that solve the problem?

Comment: your STS now is 32bit,so you can try to download 64bit STS.

Comment: 32 bit JRE is necessary not 32 bit JDK

Comment: but when we install JDK the JRE wil install together,so I think he should change JDK .if you only change the jre to 32bit and the jdk is still 64 it will also throw error

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje I thought you will access my answer ... beacause i suggest first in commend